# MAGENTO: How To Set The Default Payment Radio Button

Tags: magento, checkout

Hence I have two payment methods in my checkout the radio button seems to always default to the PayPal option.  I sort the order by credit card as 31 and PayPal as #2 and even with PayPal as #2 the radio button is still checked on paypal.

**I am in need of help on what to change in the `methods.phtml` file that will make the credit the default selection.

Answer (score 8):

By using Jquery to make the default payment selection as a credit card payment in your site.

Add the below script on your method.phtml file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var j = jQuery.noConflict(); 

        j(document).ready(function() 
        { 

            var paypal = j('#p_method_paypal').is(':checked');

            if(paypal)
            { 

            j('#p_method_paypal').removeAttr('checked'); 

            j('#p_method_credit_card').attr("checked","checked");   

            }

        });

</script>
```

**Note :** Make Sure to use the paypal & credit card radio button ids instead of `#p_method_paypal` & `#p_method_credit_card` in above script.

Comment: Wow...that was simple! Thank you

Comment: Cheers .. Glad to help you Ben